# Inkscape's stroke and fill are invisible, not opacity or 'A' value

Tags: inkscape, color, stroke, fill

I am using the new version of inkscape (1.2) on a MacBook Pro, and when I try to make lines or shapes I am unable to see the fill or stroke that I adjust. I can adjust the stroke thickness to whatever value I want, along with the stroke colour or fill colour, but I do not see any of the colour appearing. When changing the value of the stroke thickness, I can see the highlighted edges of the stroke changing appropriately (as shown below in blue), but it is not 'filling' the stroke with a colour.

I have both the 'A' and opacity values set to 100, so this is not what appears to be the common solution to similar questions I find elsewhere online.

Does anyone know what is going on, or see anything wrong with what I am doing?

[image]

This never happened to me in the old version of inkscape.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the window title, you're in outline view, where only the contours of objects are displayed as thin black lines. It's relatively easy to accidentally switch view modes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + 5</kbd>.

To go back to normal view, click on 'View → Display Mode → Normal'.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much.  I wasn’t aware of this viewing mode, and clearly didn’t notice the detail in the window title.